# Angular4 importing local js file indicates 404 not found

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I set up a new project using "ng new xxx",
 just add one line in index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bbb</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./CitrixHTML5SDK.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then put the JS file in the same dir as index.html

[the same dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDBPC.png)

But when I run "ng server", the browser always show: 404

[the js file not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRIDS.png)

Does anyone know why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that you can't simply place an external js file out of the project scope and expect it to work.

Comment: @KevinRED check my answer hope it will work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going through same issue with JSON file, so what I done is kept my JSON file in to `assets` folder. And access it through my code.

Here in [**Project file review**](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#project-file-review) you can also verify it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new folder i.e. "data". Then you will have to add "data" in "assets" array of angular-cli.json file. See below JSON data :-

```
    "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "data",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": ["data/sample.js"],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

**After that don't forget to restart the server. Otherwise you will get 404 error.**